# JQuery click counter for Flash links

Tags: php, jquery, flash

Hey there, I'm trying to create a way of when a link is clicked in my flash movie (that is embedded in html) its counted and added to a "database" so I can keep track of the hits. Bearing in mind i've got 23 different links so I need a separate count for all 23.

Thanks - Caius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few options, but frankly, I don't see how JQuery fits in.

#### Option 1: Use third party analytics software like Google Ananlytics

You can call the GA hooks in your swf to trigger specific content views, or you can use javascript to update the browsers anchor location ( `http://mysite.com#link1`, `http://mysite.com#link2`, etc...)

#### Option 2: Roll your own simple tracker

When the user clicks on a trackable item in your swf, call a script on your server that updates your database. a simple PHP script could handle that.

cheers.

Comment: Cheers, all those options sound great, I might play with Google Spreadsheet API might be a good way of creating live visualisations of the hits, which fits nicely into my project.